# Rollback a wrong push to master

Tags: git

I am new to Git and wanted to first create a branch and push my changes to it, but accidentally I just pushed my changes to the whole master. Now how can I rollback those changes?

Can I use any of these buttons in the picture below?

Image in here,  I am new to SO so I can't upload directly:

http://i49.tinypic.com/1zyu250.png

Comment: Do you want the fact that you did a rollback to be part of the repository history?

Comment: Are you working on this on your own, or as part of a team?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already sent the commit to the remote repository, you should use revert. It will create a new commit reverting the changes that you did. To use it, you need to pass the hash of the commit that you want to revert the changes:

```
git revert commit-hash
```

If you want to delete the commit from the repository, you can use git reset to return your repository to a state before the wrong commit. To do this, you need the hash of the commit before the wrong commit:

```
git reset --hard commit-hash
```

This will delete all changes that were done after the wrong commit too. And to delete the commits from the remote repository, you need to pass the option -f to `git push` because you are changind the repository history:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: Thanks, so first I should go inside the folder of my code and then use that command ?

Comment: yeah. You should enter the repository folder first. To look the history, you can use `git log`.

Comment: Thanks, so if I use git reset, it will remove my wrong commit from the repo BUT it will NOT make any changes to my local code changes? righyt? Because I don't want to lose the code I have written, locally

Comment: If you pass the option --hard, it will delete the changes. If want to preserve the changes, just don't use the option --hard. The changes will appear in `changes not staged for commit` state. You can see it with `git status`.